# oci8 on Ubuntu error

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oci8

I have already installed oracle xe 10g, apache, php in ubuntu by following the ebook [Underground Oracle-PHP-manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).  But when i run some file connection oracle-PHP using oci_connect() show error :

```
Warning: oci_connect() [function.oci-connect]: OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. 
There is something wrong with your system - 
please check that ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
are set and point to the right directories   
in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/con_oracle.php on line 2
```

HELP please !!!

Comment: Probably a better question for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) or perhaps [Ubuntu - Stack Exchange](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I spent more than 6 hours with this error.
All variables were set well, read permissions on the oracle folder set, dozens of pages on internet read, but no way to solve this.

Finally I tried the last thing.
The failure *OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed* is due to permissions on a folder */opt/oracle/instantclient* anyway! When I set the owner and group to `www-data` (in my case), the connection was established successfully! :-)
I read about permissions over the net, but it was not clearly such this.

The strange thing is that is the second time I am installing this module, and the first one had no such problems!

I am expect this may help to anyone, even to me when I need to install it again in the future! :-D
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

So, do $ORACLE_HOME and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH point to the right directories?

Comment: Particularly remembering that Apache is probably running as daemon or guest or some other user, you need to ensure that ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are available for that account, setting them up in /usr/local/apache/bin/envvars if necessary

Answer (score 0):

edit your envvars file in /usr/local/apache/bin/envvars

add this if you use oracle xe 10g

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib:
```

good luck :D